# LINQ | How do I get SUM without grouping?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, aggregate, sum, aggregation

Crazy question...however, I want the sum of all the rows in a table for a column (without using the group by clause)

Example:

```
Table = Survey
Columns = Answer1, Answer2, Answer3
        1        1         1
        4        3         5
        3        3         2
```

I want the sums for each column.

Final results should look like:

```
Answer1Sum  Answer2Sum  Answer2Sum

8           7           8
```

---

This doesn't work:

```
from survey in SurveyAnswers
select new
{
    Answer1Sum = survey.Sum(),
    Answer2Sum = survey.Sum(),
    Answer3Sum = survey.Sum()
 }
```

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this work:

```
var answer1Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum( survey => survey.Answer1 );
var answer2Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum( survey => survey.Answer2 );
var answer3Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum( survey => survey.Answer3 );
```

Comment: If he wants it all in one object, you can basically wrap that with a new{...}. (Not saying he does, just pointing out an option)

Comment: that would mean three different queries. Can this not be done with one query?

Comment: This is not a crazy question, its a reasonable question. Does the above code only result in one SQL Statement?

Answer (score 1):

A VB.NET soltuion to this answer for anyone that needs it is as follows:

```
Dim Answer1Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum(Function(survey) survey.Answer1)
Dim Answer2Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum(Function(survey) survey.Answer2)
Dim Answer3Sum = SurveyAnswers.Sum(Function(survey) survey.Answer3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SurveyAnswers.Sum(r => r.Answer1);
```